# How to ensure the result from for idm in range (0,n): is correct for R3_temp?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

With the same for loop (for idm in range (0,n):), I would like to get the np.shape(R3_temp) = np.shape(WL_PS_storage) = (3,).

However, from the following codes, the result of R3_temp is different.
In this case, could anyone let me know what is missed for the code here, please?

Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

w = 5
v = 3


m = np.array([2,3,2]) #parallel chambers
n = len(m)
steps = np.arange(1,n+1)
q = np.remainder(steps,2)

p_one = 30
c_one = 50

p_three = 40
c_three = 40


start_p_two = 20
start_c_two = 20

total_p_two = 21
total_c_two = 21

Total_combination = total_p_two*total_c_two

Z_comb = [np.arange(0,m[0]),np.arange(0,m[1]),np.arange(0,m[2])]
Z_comb
```

Z_comb = [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1])]

```
storage_R1_R2_max = []
for p_two in range(start_p_two,total_p_two):
    p = np.array([p_one, p_two, p_three])
    for c_two in range(start_c_two,total_c_two):
        c = np.array([c_one, c_two, c_three])

        #calculate workload
        WL_PS_storage = []

        for idm in range (0,n):
            WL_PS = (1/m[idm])*(p[idm] + c[idm] + 2*w)
            WL_PS_storage.append(WL_PS) #in the loop of idm, len WL_PS_storage = 3
        WL_PS_max = max(WL_PS_storage) #same column with for idm

        WL_robot = 2*(n+1)*(v+w)
        workload = max(WL_PS_max,WL_robot)
        
        
        R2_storage = []
        for idm in range (0,n):
        
        #calculate R2
            R2 = (1/m[idm])*(p[idm] + c[idm] + 2*w)
            R2_storage.append(R2)
            R2_max = max(R2_storage)

        #calculate R1
        R1 = (n+1)*(2*v + 2*w)
        max_R1_R2 = max(R1, R2_max)
        storage_R1_R2_max.append(max_R1_R2) 

print('shape WL_PS_storage', np.shape(WL_PS_storage))
print('WL_PS_storage', WL_PS_storage)
print('R2 storage', R2_storage)
```

shape WL_PS_storage (3,)

WL_PS_storage [45.0, 16.666666666666664, 45.0]

R2 storage [45.0, 16.666666666666664, 45.0]

```
for p_two in range(start_p_two,total_p_two):
    p = np.array([p_one, p_two, p_three])
    for c_two in range(start_c_two,total_c_two):
        c = np.array([c_one, c_two, c_three])
        
        for z_one in Z_comb[0]:
            for z_two in Z_comb[1]:
                for z_three in Z_comb[2]:
                    
                    R3_temp = []
                    for idm in range(0,n):
                        #calculate R3

                        if idm <= (n-1):
                            R3 = (q[idm]*c[idm]+ (1-q[idm])*p[idm] + (1+n)*w + n*v)* ((q[idm]/(m[idm]-z)) + ((1-q[idm])/(m[idm]-z)))
                        if idm == (n-1):
                            R3 = (q[idm]*p[idm] + (1-q[idm])*c[idm] + (1+n)*w + n*v)* (q[idm]/(m[idm]-z) + (1-q[idm])/(m[idm]-z))                                                                                                                              
                            R3_temp.append(R3)

print('np shape R3_temp', np.shape(R3_temp))
print('R3_temp', R3_temp)
```

np shape R3_temp (1, 2)

R3_temp [array([34.5, 69. ])]

Comment: The line `R3_temp.append(R3)` is probably indented one level too far.

Comment: I tried to put it one level back (now is inline with the if's), then R3_temp = [array([39.5, 79. ]), array([16.33333333, 24.5       ]), array([34.5, 69. ])].

Comment: I actually tried to run it and got a shape `(3,)`. I set `z=0` as that was missing but not sure if that matters. Result values: `[39.5, 16.333333333333332, 34.5]`